# How to get percentage of duration after date added by Duration?

Tags: php, vb.net, percentage

I have several task:

```
$submitted = "Friday, April 11, 2014 02:55 PM"
$duration = "3 Month"
$execution = "Friday, April 13, 2014 02:55 PM"
```

With my algorithm is

```
$percentage = calculate ($execution+$duration) - $submitted 
$percentage = $percentage divided by 100%.
```

But is that enough? I mean the logical way it seem only subtraction, after the execution date is added by the duration.
But in details, seems that variable for the $duration may be difference. The above case is only for month **duration**. How about when it is **Year duration**? and how about **days duration**?

Ya, how to do it in Php & VB.net? Both have its own language.

Comment: Take a look at date_diff() examples (http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php)

Comment: could you please explain you real "case" behind your question. I don't understand for what this might be useful.

Comment: @NorthBridge the main purpose is to calculate the final date from the first date + the date started (executed). Lastly, make the date length calculated as percentage. CMIIW.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this to get the differnce between two dates:

```
$datetime1 = new DateTime('Friday, April 11, 2014 02:55 PM');
$datetime2 = new DateTime('Sunday, April 13, 2014 02:55 PM');
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
```

now you have 2 options:

Use the format option:

```
echo $interval->format('%d Days');
```

Example output:

```
2 Days
```

Or use the array with diff:

```
print_r($interval) ;
```

Example output of the array:

```
DateInterval Object
(
    [y] => 0
    [m] => 0
    [d] => 2
    [h] => 0
    [i] => 0
    [s] => 0
    [weekday] => 0
    [weekday_behavior] => 0
    [first_last_day_of] => 0
    [invert] => 0
    [days] => 2
    [special_type] => 0
    [special_amount] => 0
    [have_weekday_relative] => 0
    [have_special_relative] => 0
)
```